# Problem solving faulty sodium bulb circuit

Tags: transformer, lamp

We have lab equipment at work with a sodium bulb.
The bulb is getting power but does not illuminate. Just a small glow.

Can somebody point to a possible cause of the problem? Or even just give me the name for this type of circuit so I can read further.

So far we have:
Swapped the bulb for a known good one.
Tested capacitance of the cap 4.6 uF (within stated 10% of rated value)

The thing that is confusing me is how the coil is wired. I have used step up/down transformers but this only has one wire coming out of the secondary coil? I think? Honestly that is my guess looking at it.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have an external starter?

Comment: It's all contained within the unit. The circuit is the same as the diagram depicted in on of the pictures, with the addition of a switch.

Comment: Glow-starter in the base of the bulb or does the actual sodium part of the lamp light up (although perhaps only the mercury lines if it never reaches anything but low power)?

Comment: A low-pressure sodium? Did you wait patiently for it to warm up? I recall these take about 10 minutes to come up fully.

Comment: @winny there is a small glow at the base of the bulb which I assume is the starter?

Comment: @glen_geek you are correct, but it should light significantly more than it is during that warm up phase

Comment: Most probably. Probe it with a multimeter? Bad connection somewhere?

Comment: Don't overlook the obvious.. check that the connections are all solid, especially the lamp base.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 components in your setup. One is the lamp which has been swapped with a known good one. Two is the capacitor which has been measured as having the correct capacitance. Three is the ballast. Assuming the AC input is correct, the process of elimination points to the ballast. Either swap it with a known good one or replace it.

Comment: is there anyway to test the ballast with a multimeter? just to confirm before buying anything? management have already put in an order for a replacement unit, but it would be good to keep this going as a secondary unit.

Comment: I have just disconnected the ballast and measured 40ohms across where the bulb was connected and 6ohms across the live and nuteral terminals. reading elsewhere it should be much higher than that